# How to programatically determine the name of the active control in livecode

Tags: livecode

I have a code script in a stack that runs `on KeyboardActivated`. The codes needs the name of the active control. I can get that by adding `on openfield` code for each control that generate a KeyboardActivated. But is would be much easier of there was a way for the stack to  know which control is active. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a front script. To designate a script a front script, use this syntax

```
insert the script of control x into front
```

You can use an `openField` handler:

```
global gLastOpenedField

on openField
  put the long id of the target into gLastOpenedField
  pass openField
end openField
```

The front script will catch all openField handlers and store the long id of the target into a global variable. Don't forget to pass the `openField` message on to the next level!

Comment: What do you mean by "Don't forget to pass the openField message on to the next level". Also what will happen if the control also have openfield script?

Comment: Also in the code `insert the script of control x into front`, do I have to do that for each control or would it apply to all control. Typically, I would like it to apply to all text entry field

Comment: @Sheils look at the `pass`command. It is needed to make other `openField` handlers work. You need to do this only once.

Answer (score 0):

That is what Mark meant. If you trap the "openField" message in a frontScript, and do not pass it, it will be processed, but then discarded. The "pass" command does just that, sends it along the hierarchy.

You can think about this the other way around. If there were no "openField" handler in "front" at all, the message would pass normally through that hierarchy level without being trapped, (this is the normal way) and would then be available to be caught by that field you mentioned.

All handlers work this way. When a message is trapped, it is processed and discarded, unless explicitly passed. The only other way around this trashing is to use the "send" or "dispatch" commands, which can "pass" the message to any object, regardless of its place in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks dunbarx but it does not seem to work. I have this code in the stack `on openField
   
   put the long id of the target into gLastOpenedField
   answer gLastOpenedField
   pass openfield
   
end openField` and nothing happens when I click in the controls.

Comment: Also it is not clear where the script `insert the script of control x into front` should go. In stack or control, within a procedure or at the top of the module

Comment: If I place your handler in the stack script, and then open (focus into, put the cursor into, whatever) a field, I get the long ID of that field in the dialog. As for where to insert a script into the front, that process can be done anywhere; it is a permanent part of the stack, built into the message hierarchy, and need only be done once.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "the target"? I never use front/back scripts and always get things sorted that way. ie:

```
on KeyboardActivated
  put [short] name of the target into MyVar
-- do your stuff
```

Comment: The problem is that the `keyboardActivated` message is sent to the card rather than a control. You can use `the target`, but not in the way you propose. Have a look at my answer.